# How do I count vowels in a string C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a program that is designed to count the vowels in a word, however I am having trouble counting the vowels per word. My current code looks like this:

```
    string word;
    string[] ca = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" };
    int va = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ca.Contains(word))
        {

            label1.Text = "Vowel Count: " + va;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Vowel Count: " + va;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you wrote now checks of the word exists in the array of vowels, which of course it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to split the string into words to start with. This can be achieved with the help of the string `Split()` method:

```
// you need to decide what the word separators are:
var words = text.Split(new char[]{'.', ',', ':', ';', '\r', '\t', '\n'});
```

Once done it's just a for loop:

```
foreach (var word in words)
{
    foreach (var character in word)
    {
        if (vowels.Any(x => x == character))
          ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
string word = "myword";
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
int vowelCount = word.Count(x => vowels.Contains(Char.ToLower(x)));
```